# Salvando objetos com jpa em transação com spring

Tags: java, jsf, spring, jpa-2.0

Bom dia, vem ocorrendo um problema na aplicação que trabalho quando persisto o objeto no banco vejo o log do jboss mostrar a instrução de insert mais o id do objeto continua nulo. Não atualiza.
Como faço para evitar isso?
O forçar a finalização de uma transação do spring?

Segue o serviço:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void salvar(Pessoa editado){

        try{
            Usuario usuario = LoginControlador.getInstancia().getUsuarioSessao();
            editado.setInterligaLogSistemas(usuario.getInterligaLogSistemas());                     
            editado = validacao(editado);

            if(!editado.isAlterou() || validaAlterarStatus()){
                System.out.println("ERRO ao SALVAR PESSOA.");
                return;
            } else {
                ContextoUtil.limparMessageList();
                if (editado.getId() == null || editado.getId() == 0) {
                    editado.setId(null);                    

                    //Padronizando todos os nome em caixa alta
                    editado.setNome(editado.getNome().toUpperCase());
                    editado.setNome(ModificarStrings.removerEspacosDesnecessarios(editado.getNome()));
                    if(validarDuplicacao(editado)){
                        dao.salvar(editado);
                    } else {            
                        String str = "Não é permitido cadastrar pessoas com mesmo CPF.";
                        CentralMensagens.setarMensagemAviso(str);
                        throw new Exception(str);
                    }

                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Salvo!", "Com sucesso!"));                  
                }
                else {                                      
                    alterar(editado);
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Alterado!", "Com sucesso!"));                   
                }                                       
                ContextoUtil.setObjetoSessao(nomeObjetoSessao, editado);                
            }
            System.out.println(getClass().getName().toString() + " id = " + editado.getId());           
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            getLog().gravarArquivo(e);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Houve uma falha.", "Contactar o Administrador do Sistema."));
        } catch(Exception e){
            getLog().gravarArquivo(e);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Não foi possivel inserir ou alterar os dados.", "Contactar o Administrador do Sistema."));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
```

Segue o DAO:

```
public void salvar(E entidade) {
        em.persist(entidade);
}
```

> 14:36:26,890 INFO  [stdout] ( ) Hibernate: insert into pessoa
>   (id_Interliga_Log_Sistemas, cpf, dataAlteracao, dataFinal,
>   dataInclusao, dataNascimento, documento_identidade, email, nome,
>   pessoaIdFT, sexo, id_tipoPessoa) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?)
>
> 14:36:31,291 INFO  [stdout] ( ) com.model.servico.PessoaService id =
>   null

Reparem que pego id que deveria ser gerado pelo persist e o id continua NULL

Comment: Pode mostrar seu código para que fique mais fácil ajudar? Obrigado!

Comment: É mais fácil responder essa pergunta olhando o código :)

Comment: O `@Id` na sua entidade está anotado com `@GeneratedValue`? Para atualizar na hora você deve forçar o *flush*, então depois do `em.persist(entidade);` faça `em.flush();`, veja se isto resolve para você.

Comment: bom pensei fazer isso mais não atrapalha a transanção se houver erro para dar roolback